# Nonlinear PDE from Riemannian Geometry

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

I am wondering if anyone knows an approach to finding solutions to the following PDE:

$-e^{-2u}\Delta u=\alpha$.

Here $u=u(x,y)$ is an unknown real-valued function of 2 variables and $\alpha$ is a constant. I'd be happy to see a solution on any connected open subset of the plane.

I have 2 basic observations to get us started. The first is that we can reduce to a nonlinear second order ODE by looking for functions of the radius $r$ (or maybe $r^2$ to avoid square roots). Second, the left hand side shows up if one calculates $\Delta (e^{-2u})$. Looking at the result of the substitution, I'm not sure if this helps.

For context, the quantity on the left side of the equation above is the sectional or Gauss curvature of a metric which is conformal by the factor $e^{2u}$ to the standard Euclidean metric on the plane. Thus solving the above would be a simple way to give examples of constant curvature metrics in two dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

In fact this belongs to a PDE of the form http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/npde/npde3103.pdf.

The general solution is $u(x,y)=-\ln\dfrac{\sqrt{|\alpha|}\left(1-\text{sgn}(\alpha)f(x+iy)\overline{f(x+iy)}\right)}{2|f_{x+iy}(x+iy)|}$

Comment: Thank you for the information. Do you have any idea how to approach solving the equation? I'm pleasantly surprised to know it has an exact general solution, but I'm more interested in the approach.

Comment: I agree that the solution you wrote above conforms in our case with the solution given in the link. However, when I tried the simplest harmonic function I could think of, $f(z)=z$, and plugged it into the equation, I got $-e^{-2u}\Delta u=-\alpha$, instead of $\alpha$ on the RHS. I am led to believe that there should be a minus sign in front of the $sgn$ terms. This is supported by the fact that, with this change, one recovers the classical 2-sphere and Poincaré disk models using $f(z)=z$.

Comment: The general solution in that link seems to be incorrect. I checked it by trying $f(z)=e^z$ as my harmonic function and the two sides were off by a factor of $-\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try $\phi (x, y ) =e ^ { -2u}$, then you get $-\Delta\phi=-\alpha$ This is Poisons Equation, Solve This For $\phi $ Substitute In For $u$ And Then $\ln $ It All.

Comment: If you calculate $\Delta \phi$ you don't quite get the left hand side of the equation...

Comment: I thought $\Delta (e ^ { - 2u })=-e ^ { - 2u }\Delta u$? So if $\phi =e ^ { - 2u }$ This should all hold correctly?

Comment: $\Delta f=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}$ by definition. One gets another term involving the norm-square of the gradient of $u$ when calculating $\Delta \phi$.

Comment: Also, is the surface we are looking parametrized as $(x,y,u(x,y))$?

Comment: We're working in the plane, so we just have standard $x$ and $y$ coordinates. The function $u$ is not related to any kind of parametrization.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is, if we solve the pde for $u$, are you assuming that the surface would be given by $u$? or is $u$ just part of the metric?

Comment: I'm endowing the plane with the metric $g=e^{2u}\delta$, where $\delta$ is the standard Euclidean metric. The PDE arises when you calculate the curvature and ask that it be constant.

Comment: This probably sounds dumb, but a plane would have zero curvature? How can you endow it with a metric that can induce non constant curvature?

Comment: Curvature is determined completely by the metric. When you say a plane has zero curvature, what you mean is that a plane with a Euclidean metric has zero curvature. One of the most well-known examples is the hyperbolic plane, which is modeled by the set $y>0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, has a metric conformal to the standard Euclidean metric as above, and has constant curvature equal to -1.